# How to wait while function is finished?

Tags: angular-services, angular9

I'm using `angular 9` and I have some service that performs asynchronously and I need synchronize it. My code looks like the following:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GoogleAuthService {

  constructor() {
    console.log('start initialize');
    const libURL = "https://my.js";
    this.loadScript(libURL)
      .then(() => this.loadAuth2Library())
      .then(() => this.initAuth2Client())
      .then(() => {
          console.log("ddd");
          this.next();
        })
      .catch(reason => {
        console.log("hasn't been initialized.", reason);
      });
    console.log('end initialize');
  }
}
```

and I need to wait for when all constructor has been performed and then goes to the next step but in this case, I see in the console:

```
start initialize
end initialize
ddd
```

but I need:

```
start initialize
ddd
end initialize
```

Answer (score 0):

> performs asynchronously and I need synchronize it

Asynchronous functions are asynchronous for a reason. If you need to perform something after all the asynchronous calls are complete, then move it inside the last call. You cannot make something outside the asynchronous call to wait until it is complete.

In your case, whatever you wish to do after the calls should be moved inside like following

```js
constructor() {
  console.log('start initialize');
  const libURL = "https://my.js";
  this.loadScript(libURL)
    .then(() => this.loadAuth2Library())
    .then(() => this.initAuth2Client())
    .then(() => {
        console.log("ddd");
        this.next();
        console.log('end initialize');
      })
    .catch(reason => {
      console.log("hasn't been initialized.", reason);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

anything you wish to execute after those async functions should be inside the last THEN clause. This is because your code is async.

You may call a function after the line " console.log("ddd");"

and inside that function put the code you need to execute after initialization.

cheers